# Stop While Loop w/ Variable Flag

Tags: python-3.x

I'm unable to figure out why 'quit' doesn't change my variable flag to False; stopping the while loop. Error below.

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "7.6_3_exits.py", line 11, in <module>
    age = int(age)
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "'quit'"*

prompt = "How old is the movie goer today? "
prompt += "\nYou can enter 'quit' to end: "

active = True
while active:
    age = input(prompt)
    if age == 'quit':
        active = False

    age = int(age)

    if age < 3:
        print(" Congratulations! You get in for free.")
    elif age < 13:
        print(" The cost of your ticket is $10.")
    else:
        print(" Your ticket cost is $15.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that even if your flag variable is false the `while` loop will continue until its finished before it checks if `active` is still true. Instead you can use the keyword `break` (instead of `active = false`) which will immediately stop your while loop.

Your error arises because of the same reason (the while loop continues so age is still "quit" and a string with letters cannot be converted to int).

Just a tip:
You should also surround the age = int(age) in a `try / except` as the user might type "a" which will lead to the same error. The `try / except` would look like this:

```
try:
    age = int(age)
except ValueError:
    #user didnt type a number as input
    continue #continue means start the loop from the beginning (so it won't execute 
             #the rest of the code and instead ask again for a number)
```